# How can I get just the table of contents to take the full page width?

Tags: table-of-contents, margins, templates

I am using the template provided from http://hci.rwth-aachen.de/karrer_thesistemplate for my master thesis. The template is built so that there are margin notes at each page and is using the book class, so the text in any page is only taking around 60%.

This is good for me but the problem is with the table of contents. Since there are no margin notes I would like to have the contents taking the whole width of the page. How do I do this for just the table of contents?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Why do you want to change the settings? The template is provided by the university and so the result too ;-). If you don't have any formatting rules you should avoid this template. At a first glance the template has some LaTeX mistakes. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: My supervisor really likes the template but he does not like the table of contents :S thats why i am tempted to change it :)

Comment: maybe check if the template loads the `geometry` package to change the margins. If it does, you can create a new geometry for the `toc` and switch to the standard page layout afterwards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your main file, load the `geometry` package before including the file i10preamble:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\include{i10preamble}
```

and then add the following lines:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
   \newgeometry{textwidth=14cm}
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \restoregeometry
    }
\makeatother
```

The idea is to define a new geometry for the ToC and then to restore the default values.

Comment: This worked magically :) thanks a million (can't help but say thanks..i know the rules say upvoting is enough..)

Comment: @mariamhassib You're welcome!